# how to shutdown Jupyter Notebook When there is not activity

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook:

```
[Config option `shutdown_no_activity_timeout` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in a linux base. Open the terminal and do the folowing:

```
ps -e | grep jupyter (look at the pid of the jupyter process)
kill -9 pid (the pid of the previous jupyter process)
```